# Book recommendation for Putnam/Olympiads

Tags: soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

I have been concentrating on olympiad questions, and **PUTNAM exams,** Putnam is my **main focus.** Can you suggest a book from one of these:

1. [Problem  Solving Strategies By Arthur Engel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982191)
2. [Putnam and Beyond by Andreescu Titu et. al](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387257659)

**First,** can you tell me which one is better from the above? I only have one choice?

**Any other book recommendations is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: I have heard the second one is quite good, but I have not dealt with it much. My answer below will refer you on to some more comprehensive materials that should greatly help you in preparation for the Putnam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How could you do better than the problems and solutions themselves for past Putnam exams?

1. [1938-1964](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883854627)
2. [1965-1984](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883854635)
3. [1985-2000](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883858274)

For a Putnam archive of past exam questions and solutions, check out [this](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/) website maintained by Kiran Kedlaya.

There are, of course, many other resources, but these are by far the best I know to date.

Comment: Not that I'm endorsing this, but I know these books may all be found here as PDFs: http://bookzz.org/

Comment: Yes, but I need to learn the material, and strategies first

Comment: The second book you had listed would be great for strategies, but the books I enumerated will give you an unparalleled sample size of problems which may be tackled with such strategies. I'd recommend purchasing the book by Titu and then getting the PDFs of the books I listed.

Comment: What about Problem Solving strategies? Is it any good?

Comment: From a cursory inspection, it *looks* good, but I'm only basing that on some of the reviews and the quality of the series in which the book was published--I have never actually heard of that book though to be honest. Heard the second one mentioned quite a few times. Using that second book, in combination with those four other resources...that would be dynamite.

Comment: @Amad27: Engel's book is very good. It is, however, very much Olympiad-oriented.

Comment: @AndréNicolas which one do you prefer? Putnam and beyond or Problem solving stratgies?

Comment: For high school students preparing for our Olympiad, or the IMO, Engel. For Putnam, there is lots of stuff, the books mentioned in the answers, also online stuff from training programs/courses various universities.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I am in High-School, but I want to prepare earlier for Putnam. I will use Induktio's online resources, **but** what book would you say I should get From *Problem Solving Strategies* or *Putnam and Beyond* in **order to learn the TECHNIQUES first?** Thanks AndreNicolas!