# Olympiad style polynomials book?

Tags: polynomials, book-recommendation

Can you recommennd me polynomial book which is for olympiad style polynomials? It should be for a beginner.
Thanks!

Comment: See the [Art of Problem Solving Website](https://artofproblemsolving.com/) and search the bookstore and resources listed (some downloadable).

Comment: Also have a look at "olympic" [recommendations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118585/book-recommendation-for-putnam-olympiads?rq=1) in general (including polynomials).